# Get check box value in jQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to get a check box value in jQuery.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() {
        var tObj = $('#checkpermission');
        var tVal = tObj.val();
        alert(tVal);     
    });
});

$query="select * from tbl_user where username!='admin' and password!='admin' order by username limit  $eu, $limit";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   <td><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" name="checkuser" id="checkpermission" onclick="changePage()" value='<?=$data[0]?>'></td>
  <?php
}
```

Every time I only get the first value.  What am doing wrong?

Comment: The first value of what? In the SQL query or the jQuery selector? I'm confused.

Comment: it seems you are mixing javascript and php, is this the real code you use?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of `.val`: http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').bind('click',function() 
   {
     alert($(this).is(":checked"));
     //Or you could use alert($(this).attr("checked") == "checked");
   });
});
```

Update: Have added check to see whether the checkbox is checked.

Comment: use change event for checkbox!

Comment: yes thanks ...how can i identify when i click check box is checked or not?

Comment: so here when first time click checkbox i need to update some value in database using ajax and again i click checkbox uncheck then update another value in database so how can i check is it checked or not?

Comment: Have Updated to check whether it is checked.  Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

you are only getting the first value as your checkboxes have all the same `id` and you are not iterating over the checkboxes in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Same comments as previous, but you can do this to correctly determine whether a particular checkbox is checked:

```
var tVal=tObj.is(":checked");
```

Hope that helps! Neil